# How to let students answer a Moodle Quiz by typing (or pasting) LaTeX code?

Tags: latex

Good morning,
I use Moodle for Mathematics High Schools Students.

They have to reply to questions by writing some short formulas. I've not yet figured out a way of doing this without installing additional plugins. Plugins are a headache when it comes to upgrading Moodle.

There's seem to be no question type able to give this possibility.

I already asked for help on the Moodle forum but they didn't reply or misunderstood the question.
I also tried on Twitter and Reddit, but to no avail.

Looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: You can let them type the code as plain text even if it is not displayed correctly.  For example, they can just type, say, \sqrt{x^2+y^2}.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche  The trouble with code as plain text is that if you are new to latex or not very good at it, you won't know if you typed what you meant to type without seeing it converted to the correct display.

Comment: parsing latex-like input for its mathematical meaning is very hard - there is no reasonable way to do this without plugins.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what sorts of expressions you need the students to be able to express.  Surely you don't need all of Latex's power.

Comment: Is the idea that you have Moodle assignments and you want students to be able to type LaTeX for their answers, and then have Moodle automatically grade them? Or do you just want to see their nicely-typed math and grade it manually?

Comment: The things is we have a converter from free handwriting to LaTex. So students handwrite, then the external tool converts to LaTeX, and Moodle editor should convert to human readable and gradable formulas.

Comment: Current widely distributed versions of Moodle do not have this functionality.